# Mat-table sticky header randomly disappears

Tags: angular, firefox, angular-material

I have an Angular project with an Angular Material mat-table.
I has a sticky header that works fine most of the time.
But sometimes if the table is scrolled, it randomly disappears.

The issue only occurs with Firefox, not with Chrome.

Here is a link to a video showing the issue: https://youtu.be/jIXzCeEHmCg

This is my code:

```
<mat-table
  #table
  [dataSource]="dataSource"
  class="assets-table"
>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="identifier" sticky>...</ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="description" sticky>...</ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="hierarchie" sticky>...</ng-container>

  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="extraParameter.name" *ngFor="let extraParameter of extraParameters">...</ng-container>

  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="lastEventColumnName" *ngFor="let lastEventColumnName of lastEventColumnsNames">...</ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="action1" stickyEnd>...</ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="action2" stickyEnd>...</ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="action3" stickyEnd>...</ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

</mat-table>
```

I'm using Angular 11 and tested with Firefox 91 and 100.

Edit: I created a Stackblitz with a exemple showing the issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hcfg6f?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: It's not very helpful if you show the problem through a video because nobody will be able to reproduce the problem from only that or the bit of code you posted. Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
showing the problem.
You could use [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com) to create a MRE.

Comment: I added a link to a Stackblitz. Sorry for the delay.